# '(struct student *)&st' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?|

Tags: c

[image: screenshot]

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 50

struct student
{
   int srn;
   char stu_name[30];
   char course[18];
   char addr[50];
};

int main()
{
    struct student st[MAX];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter name of the student %d : ", st[i].srn=i+1);
        scanf("%s", st[i].stu_name);
        printf("\nEnter course of the student %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", st[i].course);
        printf("\nEnter address of the student %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", st[i].addr);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("\nname of student %d is %s", i+1, st[i].stu_name);
        printf("\ncourse is %s", st[i].course);
        printf("\naddr is %s", st[i].addr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

i wrote this code for a school project but codeblocks keeps giving me this error.Anyone know the solution?
`main.c|21|error: '(struct student *)&st' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?|`

Comment: The error message does not seem to match the code shown. There is no `&st` nor `&stun` in the code. Please check that and post the **exact** code.

Comment: `st.srn=i+1` should be `st[i].srn=i+1`.  Not sure if that's your bug though.

Comment: And for the next question you're going to have as soon as you get your code to compile and run: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin

Comment: @kaylum please refer to the screenshot. i have run the code multiple times and yet it keeps giving me the same error. even though &st is not in the code.

Comment: You are probably not compiling what you think you are. Copy the code to another file and remove the content from the original file. Then try to compile again to see if you still get the same error.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't result in the error you claim it does. The answer addresses the problem in the code you posted, which is the best we can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign values in the same line where you are printing them, thats the whole problem

try this instead might work

```
st[i+1].srn
```

instead of

```
st[i].srn=i+1
```

The end code should look something like this

```
int main()
{
    struct student st[MAX];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        st[i].srn = i+1;
        printf("\nEnter name of the student %d : ", st[i].srn);
        scanf("%s", st[i].stu_name);
        printf("\nEnter course of the student %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", st[i].course);
        printf("\nEnter address of the student %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%s", st[i].addr);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        printf("\nname of student %d is %s", i+1, st[i].stu_name);
        printf("\nname of student %d is %s", st[i].srn, st[i].stu_name);
        printf("\ncourse is %s", st[i].course);
        printf("\naddr is %s", st[i].addr);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed it, try this out

Comment: thank you.This worked. i really need to revise my topics in c XD

Comment: works for me https://repl.it/@IgorStepansky/GoldenInfiniteAttribute#main.c

Comment: Using `st[i].srn=i+1` as an argument to `printf` may not be good style but it's certainly legal.  Assignment expressions yield the value assigned.